# Easily Creating Dynamic Form/Controls Within Qt

Tags: winforms, qt, forms

We've got a Qt application that configures external devices by querying their configure interface and then, using a QWebView, we present an HTML page with the appropriate controls.  We'd prefer to hand the configuration information to some sort of Qt "Form Builder" class, and have it spit out a QWidget with a layout that contains native Qt controls.  (We fully own the interface information, and so can turn it into whatever format this mythical "QFormBuilder" takes.)

Is this possible?  No one really wants to budget the time to write our own parser (or use QScript for the same reason), as the HTML version looks "good enough".  However, if there is an alternative, I'd love to know what other people have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  You can write the UI information in the same format Qt Designer uses, then construct the UI at runtime using the [QUiLoader](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/quiloader.html) class.